# How to set a one-sided container in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have set up a `container` class as such:

```css
.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: min(90%, 70.5rem);
}
```

This would allow me to set a container to contain the content of the web page in the center of the page (much more organized). However, I would like to have one custom container where, the margin only exists on the left side of the page, allowing the content to overflow on the right side of the page. How should I modify my code to do this? I've used `margin-left` before but this is not responsive unlike the code I provided above.

Comment: `margin-left` is indeed responsive, provided you use a response unit of measure.

Comment: @ObsidianAge True, I've used `margin-left: 12.5vw` to line the margin with the code above on a certain window width. However, when I resize the window, it doesn't line up anymore. I'm trying to find a solution where it would line up with the code I used above.

Comment: So you meant your `.container` is still in center, and you have a custom one on the left side of `.container`?

Comment: margin-left: auto will automatically take all the space in the left as margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below. I kept both methods so you can compare the code:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: min(90%, 70.5rem);
}

.new-container {
  margin-left: calc((100% - min(90%, 70.5rem))/2);
}

[class] {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-block: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="new-container"></div>
```